# What is "2DIN" in the context of car radio interfaces?

Tags: power-supply, dc, automotive, computers

I want to install a custom computer in lieu of my radio in my 1996 Volvo 850. I have seen various kits, such as [one offering a barebones "2DIN" computer](http://e3io.com/2din-amd-carpc-barebone). What does this mean?

(My main concern is basically hooking the power supply of the car to the computer. Since the car can turn off and on and generate DC surges, obviously the computer needs to have a specialized 12V DC power supply of some kind.)

Answer (score 2):

There is an old standard for car radio mounting, it's called the “DIN-Schacht” or “DIN slot“ (simply translated from German). In the past, all German car manufacturers (and a lot of other, too) had one or two of those slots installed in every vehicle, so you could easily fit in a third-party car stereo, a CB radio, a trip recorder or taxi meter in the car.

2DIN is a special case of two slots directly above of each other, so either two standard-height or one 2DIN appliance fits. Unfortunately, this standard isn't nearly as widespread as the *DIN-Schacht* was, so you have to check your car manual if that thing would fit. Unlikely, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Several sources I could find indicate there are some type of plastic rails on the inside of the double-DIN hole in the dash of that car. There is a forum post here that goes into more detail regarding a '97 volvo double-DIN configuration: https://volvoforums.com/forum/volvo-850-16/aftermarket-850-stereo-options-63839/

I worked as a professional car stereo installer for a number of years during that time frame but I can't recall that particular make and model.

I looked at the computer you referenced and if the other sources are correct, it looks like you'd have to file down the rails to fit it in your dash (which purportedly would not allow you to re-insert the factory stereo if you wished to sell the car with the factory system).

There is also a good chance you'd have to modify the trim bezel, therefore you might want to investigate an aftermarket dash kit (some of which would come with a standard 2-DIN bezel trim piece).

When installing into vehicles like volvos, bmw's etc, it was always a good idea to purchase a wiring kit (which plugs into the factory harness and provides you with labeled connections to the speakers and power etc.) It makes installation much easier and usually means you don't have to cut into the factory wiring.

Another post I found indicated that some carpc 2-DIN units are very deep and didn't fit depth-wise: http://www.diymobileaudio.com/forum/car-pc-tablet-installation-forum/157332-e3io-car-pc-lets-talk-about.html

Just my personal opinion, but I'd want to ask the manufacturer for a manual before buying one and I couldn't easily locate one on their website or by google. If you happen to find one, I'd be curious to look at it.

I also found an interesting video from the manufacturer that shows them building one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THRyVntm_DM